# How to extract first observation satisfying a condition within a list of matrix?

Tags: r, list, matrix, simulation

I have a list of 100 matrix from a simulation. Each matrix is 100x3. I need generate a new matrix containing the first observation that satisfy  matrix[,2]>9 in each matrix from the list.

I did something similar (generate a matrix containing first observation of the matrix in the list) using the following code.

```
oferta_1=do.call(rbind,lapply(matrices, head, 1)) #where matrices is a list of 100 matrix 100x3
```

How can I do the same but with the condition "first observation that satisfy matrix[,2]>9"?

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
oferta_1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(matrices, function(x) x[which.max(x[,2] > 9), ]))
```

Or probably safer :

```
oferta_1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(matrices, function(x) x[which(x[,2] > 9)[1], ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

do.call(rbind, lapply(matrices, function(x) x[which.max(x[,2] > 9), ]))